# javascript for a health tool

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m a med student  and I’m trying to develop a health tool to be use in the primary care in my city. It’s basically a form to filled with patient’s information regarding endocrinology issues. But I need to calculate a score with some information and I’m not sure how to do it.
I have these four tables/sections and anytime the person chooses the option “SIM” (the tool it’s in Portuguese ) in any of list items I need that it counts 1 in that section.

So it would be like this 
If  PsP = 0 AND DAP = 0 AND UlcAmp=0 regardless of  Deformidades 
then Risk = 0;
If PSP = 1 AND DAP = 0 AND UlcAmp=0 regardless of  Deformidades 
then Risk = 1;
If DAP = 1 AND UlcAmp=0 regardless of  PSP AND Deformidades 
then Risk = 2;
IF UlcAmp = 1 regardless of PSP AND DAP AND Deformidades
then Risk = 3

And for each risk I’ll have a message displayed in the last table bellows "Resultado".

BUT I don’t know how to implement that!
Could you help me somehow?

```js
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
<title> tool </title>
<script>
function calculate(){
var Deformidades = 0;
var PSP = 0;
var DAP = 0;
var UlcAmp = 0;
var Risk = 0;

//var inside deformidades
var PeNeuropatico = 0;
var ArcoDesabado = 0;
var Vaigismo = 0;
var DedosEmGarra = 0;
var SinalDaPrece = 0;

//var inside PSP
var SensibilidadeVibratoria = 0;
var SensibilidadeDolorosa = 0;
var SensibilidadeAoFrio = 0;
var ReflexosAquileus = 0;

//var inside DAP
var ITB  = 0;
var PulsoArterialPediosoDireito = 0;
var PulsoArterialPediosoEsquerdo = 0;
var PulsoArterialTibialPosteriorDireito = 0;
var PulsoArterialTibialPosteriorEsquerdo = 0;

//var inside UlcAmp
var AmputacaoMaior = 0;
var AmputacaoMenor = 0;
var UlceraPrevia = 0;
var UlceraNeuropatica = 0;
var UlceraIsquemica = 0;
var UlceraNeuroisquemica = 0;

</script>

<body>

<table width= "565px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0;" id="Deformidades">
    <col width="25px"/>
    <col width="120px"/>
    <col width="360px"/>
    <col width="60px"/>
    <tr>
        <td class="divCenMid" colspan = "2"> Deformidades</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Pé neuropático típico?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <select input id="PeNeuropatico"  > <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Arco Desabado (Charcot)? </td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <select input id="ArcoDesabado"  > <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop">Vaigismo? </td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
       <select input id="Vaigismo"  > <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop">Dedos em garras?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
   <select input id="DedosEmGarra"  > <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop">Limitação da mobilidade articular
(Sinal da Prece)? </td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
 <select input id="SinalDaPrece"  > <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br><br><br>
<table width= "565px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0;" id="PSP">
    <col width="25px"/>
    <col width="120px"/>
    <col width="360px"/>
    <col width="60px"/>
    <tr>
        <td class="divCenMid" colspan = "2"> Perda da Sensibilidade Protetora</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Sensibilidade vibratória diminuída ou ausente?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <select input id="SensibilidadeVibratoria"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Sensibilidade dolorosa diminuída ou ausente? </td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <select input id="SensibilidadeDolorosa"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop">Sensibilidade ao frio diminuída ou ausente? </td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
       <select input id="SensibilidadeAoFrio"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop">Reflexos aquileus diminuídos ou ausentes? </td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
   <select input id="ReflexosAquileus"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
<br><br><br>
<table width= "565px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0;" id="DAP">
    <col width="25px"/>
    <col width="120px"/>
    <col width="360px"/>
    <col width="60px"/>
    <tr>
        <td class="divCenMid" colspan = "2"> Palpação de pulsos</td>

    </tr>

    <tr>

        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Pulso arterial pedioso direito diminuído ou ausente?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <select input id="PulsoArterialPediosoDireito"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> Pulso arterial pedioso esquerdo diminuído ou ausente? </td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <select input id="PulsoArterialPediosoEsquerdo"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop">Pulso arterial tibial posterior direito diminuído ou ausente? </td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
       <select input id="PulsoArterialTibialPosteriorDireito"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop">Pulso arterial tibial posterior direito diminuído ou ausente? </td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
   <select input id="PulsoArterialTibialPosteriorEsquerdo"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

<br><br><br>
<table width= "565px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0;" id="UlcAmp">
    <col width="25px"/>
    <col width="120px"/>
    <col width="360px"/>
    <col width="60px"/>
    <tr>
        <td class="divCenMid" colspan = "2"> Úlceras e Amputações</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> O paciente possui uma amputação maior?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <select input id="AmputacaoMaior"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"> O paciente possui uma amputação menor?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
            <select input id="AmputacaoMenor"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop">O paciente possui uma úlcera prévia?</td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
       <select input id=" UlceraPrevia"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop">O paciente possui uma úlcera neuropática ativa? </td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
   <select input id="UlceraNeuropatica"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop">O paciente possui uma úlcera isquêmica ativa? </td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
   <select input id="UlceraIsquemica"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      
        <td class="allbdrLtTop">O paciente possui uma úlcera neuroisquêmica ativa? </td>
        <td class="allbdrCenMid">
   <select input id="UlceraNeuroisquemica"> <option>  Sim </option> <option> Não</option></select> 

        </td>
    </tr>

</table>

<br><br><br>
<table width= "565px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-spacing:0;" id="UlcAmp">
    <col width="25px"/>
    <col width="120px"/>
    <col width="360px"/>
    <col width="60px"/>
    <tr>
        <td class="divCenMid" colspan = "2"> Resultado</td>
        <td class="allbdrLtTop"></td>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You say *"If PSP = 1"* but how you calculate PSP? It goes up to which value? 4?

Comment: If you select "SIM" in any of the variables in PSP then it is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value and set the value of an input by targeting the `id` of that element.  You have a lot of dropdown's so here just a quick demo:

```
function calculate(){
    // get inputs
    var firstInput = document.getElementById("firstControl").value;
    var secondInput = document.getElementById("secondControl").value;

    // compare inputs
    if(firstInput == 0 && secondInput == 0){

       //Set result value to something
        document.getElementById("results").value = 0;
    }
    else{
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Then you could add a button and call this function whenever you click it like:

```
<input type="button" onclick="calculate()">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(UlcAmp == 1){
    risk=3;
} else if(DAP == 1){
    risk=2;
} else if(PSP == 1){
    risk=1;
} else {
    risk=0;
}
```

Comment: It seems like @lamelemon answered the implementation and I answered the logic.